# while requesting / after click block the button or something?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this upload then you can crop your image, but if you press twice quickly then it uploads 2 and it all gets crazy. How can i block the button RIGHT after it starts sending request, and where should i place it?

(in jquery ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<button id="foo">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#foo').click(function() {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The important part of course is $(this).attr('disabled', true); You can then enable the button again by setting the attribute to false.